# Binding of relative position of a control

Tags: wpf, canvas, binding, margin, draggable

I have a draggable user control within another user control indicating the distance of a vessel from another vessel.  The placement of the object is bound to X, Y values in the back end.  If the user loads a "mission", the location of this draggable object should snap to the position based on the X and Y values.  Additionally, if the user drags the boat but then cancels, the position of the boat should snap back to its original position before it was dragged.

I find that if I bind to the Margin field, the margin is set correctly on the control but the draggable object stays in the same place, as if it is at 0,0,0,0 with the updated values (I can force it to move by editing the xaml and proving that any margin changes act as if the new values are 0,0,0,0:

```
public Thickness DaughtershipMargin
{
    get { return _daughtershipMargin; }
    set
    {
        _daughtershipMargin = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

I have also experimented with using a Canvas instead with similar results.

When initially dragging, the position is based on the relative position of the control based on a parent control - so it needs I need to do something similar

```
private void MouseDragElementBehavior_Dragging(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    double x = System.Math.Round((e.GetPosition(colabdragObjectGrid).X - 280), 3);
    double y = System.Math.Round((-1 * (e.GetPosition(colabdragObjectGrid).Y - 280)), 3);
    if (x >= _minFollowDistance && x <= _maxFollowDistance && y >= _minFollowDistance && y <= _maxFollowDistance)
    {
        _parent.ProcessDragEvent(x.ToString(), y.ToString());
    }
}

<Grid x:Name="colabdragObjectGrid" Margin="0,-10,0,0" Height="575" Width="575">
    <local:colabdrag x:Name="colabdragObject" Height="100" Width="100" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Margin="{Binding DaughtershipMargin}">
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <ei:MouseDragElementBehavior ConstrainToParentBounds="True" Dragging="MouseDragElementBehavior_Dragging"/>
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    </local:colabdrag>
</Grid>
```

Edit:
I got this to work by creating a point relative to the draggable area and another point for the desired position based on that point, then using TranslateTranform to get the object where it needs to be

```
var pointA = (colabdragObject.TransformToAncestor(colabDragObjectGrid).Transform(new Point(X,Y))

var pointB = colabdragObjectGrid.TranslatePoint(pointA, colabDragObject);

colabdragObject.RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform(pointB.X, -1 * pointB.Y);
```

Comment: I'd recommend setting either colabdragObject.RenderTransform or colabdragObject.LayoutTransform instead of margin. Since your mouse pos is relative to your outer control, you'll probably have to figure out how to translate the coordinates. I think myPoint = colabdragObjectGrid.TranslatePoint(myPoint, colabdragObject) should do the trick, where myPoint is just a new Point(x, y)

then you can do something like this: colabdragObject.RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform(myPoint.X, myPoint.Y);

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  This works similarly to setting the margin or canvas position.  If I set the values manually in the XAML, the  position of the draggable object changes.  However when the value gets set in code-behind, the position doesn't move, even if I poke with a PropertyChanged() event

Comment: Going back to your comment and messing around a bit more, I was able to get this to work.  Thank you much!

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post your solution as an answer, so people with a similar problem can see how to do it.

Comment: Yes you're right @Shrimperator.  I have edited my question to contain the solution